# What's the best way to handle incoming messages?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, d

I'm writing a server for an online game, that should be able to handle 1,000-2,000 clients in the end. The 3 ways I found to do this were basically:

1. 1 thread/connection (blocking)
2. Making a list of clients, and loop through them (non-blocking)
3. Select (Basically a blocking statement for all clients at once with optional timeout?)

In the past I've used 1, but as we all know, it doesn't scale well. 2 is okay, but I have mixed feelings, about one client technically being able to make everyone else freeze. 3 sounds interesting (a bit better than 2), but I've heard it's not suitable for too many connections.
So, what would be the best way to do it (in D)? Are there other options?

Comment: can you make 2 and pass off the messages to a worker-thread pool?

Comment: I guess I could. But I'm not aware of built in thread pools in D, and I've never implemented something like that.

Comment: check [std.parallelism](http://www.d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html)

Comment: Interesting, thanks. One possibility could be, looping through all clients, but with a foreach parallel. Wouldn't remove the risk, but speed things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual approach is closest to 3: asynchronous programming with a higher-performance `select` alternative, such as the `poll` or `epoll` system calls on Linux, IOCP on Windows, or higher-level libraries wrapping them. D does not support them directly, but you can find D bindings or 3rd-party D libraries (e.g. Tango) providing support for them.

Higher-performance servers (e.g. nginx) use one thread/process per CPU core, and use asynchronous event handling within that thread/process.

Comment: Sounds like select is okay, but oudated. Unfortunately I couldn't find such bindings yet, and I'm not aware of a full Tango port for D2.

Comment: I think the unofficial one is more-or-less complete: https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2/tree/d2port/tango/io/selector

Comment: `select` is also slower than the newer ones for large numbers of sockets.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Although this class seems to only use select on Windows as well. But at least (e)poll on *nix. What would you consider large? 100? 1,000? 10,000?

Comment: I can't say much from personal experience. Since this problem is not specific to D, there is much research information available on the web, for example here: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: @Mars: the Linux glibc interface to `select(2)` allows the largest filedescriptor to have a value of `1023`. Since you'd have to rebuild the entire mask every single iteration, that is a _lot_ of rebuilding even well below 1000 connected sockets. I'd call 50-100 "large enough" to change away from `select(2)` to `epoll(4)`, but that's more a personal choice than a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: @sarnold: I have to support Windows as well, but it's very likely I'll use epoll for *nix, thanks.

Comment: @Mars: man, that's exactly what libev and libevent were designed for -- platform-independent async-io support. I almost mentioned it earlier, but I have _no_ idea how well they'd work with D. But if you have to do both POSIX and Windows platforms, it'd be well worth an afternoon's investigation of libev or libevent under D.

Comment: @sarnold: btw, I believe it's perfectly possible to use select with more than 1024 FDs. You just need 1) a larger fd_set 2) set the max FD count ulimit (applies anyway) 3) don't forget to specify the actual size as the first argument to select.

Comment: @sarnold: I haven't took a deep look into libev yet, but it does sound promising. I'll definitely spend that afternoon some time.

Comment: @CyberShadow: You're correct, the kernel interface looks prepared to handle arbitrary sizes; but glibc's `<linux/time.h>` has `#define FD_SETSIZE              __FD_SETSIZE`, and, `<bits/typesizes.h>` has `#define __FD_SETSIZE            1024`. Maybe glibc will let you just re-define these as you wish -- I haven't tried -- but by the time you get to rebuilding 1024-odd entries in an `fd_set`, another interface is more appropriate.

Comment: I agree about the efficiency part. If you really do want to use more that 1024 sockets with select, I heard that one nice way to do it is to use an array of `fd_set`s. So then you have `fd_set myset[(MAX_SOCKETS+FD_SETSIZE-1)/FD_SETSIZE]` and access it like `FD_SET(fd % FD_SETSIZE, myset[fd / FD_SETSIZE])`. This won't work on Windows, however - there, you just define your desired `FD_SETSIZE` before `#include`-ing `<winsock.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is to have a single thread that runs the select/pole/epoll but not process the results. Rather it queues up connections known to have results and lets a thread pool feed from that. If checking that a full request has been read in is cheap, you might do that in the poll thread with non-blocking IO and only queue up full requests.

I don't know if D provides any support for any of that aside from (possibly) the inter-thread communication and queuing.