# Equivalent of poll() or WSAPoll() for sockets in D

Tags: sockets, d

For socket programming in D, is there an equivalent of poll() (or WSAPoll() on windows)? I'm hoping to write a small single-threaded server.

I know technically you can call C functions from D and therefore the entire windows C API is available, but I was hoping for a higher level (perhaps even more cross-platform) solution?

Comment: A rather similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025986/whats-the-best-way-to-handle-incoming-messages

Comment: Ah, quite. For some reason this didn't shop up in a search for "[d] sockets", despite that being almost exactly the tags they used, perhaps I did something wrong in searching (I'm fairly inexperienced with this site).

I am not sure if this is an adequate answer or not, but for the sake of sticking to the language's inbuilt features and not dipping to any C APIs I've settled on using Socket.select() in the std.socket module. It is apparently not the best function for doing it, but it is supported in the standard library and will do for a simple single-threaded server!

Comment: As you probably already know, you should opt for `select()` only if you want your code to be as portable as possible. But for the most efficient solution you will probably want `WSAPoll()` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best alternative so far are libev or libevent bindings in the Deimos: https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos .

I also would recommend you to take a look at how VibeD guys do this stuff: http://vibed.org .